# ASP.Net page: Chrome adds a #b to the URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, url-parameters

when I open the URL

```
http://mycomputer/web/Page.aspx?OfflineMode=false&ID=2
```

Chrome will make it look like:

```
http://mycomputer/web/Page.aspx?OfflineMode=false&ID=2#b
```

The problem is that I do javascript reloads via the URL with changed parameters and this is disturbing the process.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the page online to troubleshoot it, I would say save the url as a string and then modify the string. Then trying reloading based on the new string.

Is it always just `#b` added? And do you have an inner page links?